# Solving coupled first order linear ODEs via a matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt}&=-5x+10y-30\\\frac{dy}{dt}&=-2x+3y-4\end{align}$$

I'm familiar with how to solve this system via a matrix if there were no constant terms, in this case I'm not sure how to setup the equation. The system is solvable by algebraic manipulation and differentiation to get a second order ODE, but I was wondering if it was possible with a matrix.

Comment: Offset the state vector.

Comment: There is a constant particular solution $(x_0,y_0)=(10,8)$. Now the usual argument shows that a solution of your system is the sum of a particular solution (for example, the previous one) and a  solution of the corresponding homogeneous system of equations . Hence if you know how to solve the homogeneous system using matrices, you can solve the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a linear ODE system

$$x'(t)=A \cdot x(t)+ b$$

with $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -5 & 10 \\
 -2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $b=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -30 \\
 -4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The solution then is:

$$x(t)=A^{-1}\cdot (-b+exp(A t)(b+A x_{0}))$$

with $A^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{5} & -2 \\
 \frac{2}{5} & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $x0=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_{10} \\
 x_{20} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

With the Matrixexponential

$$exp(A t)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{-t} \cos (2 t)-2 e^{-t} \sin (2 t) & 5 e^{-t} \sin (2 t) \\
 -e^{-t} \sin (2 t) & 2 e^{-t} \sin (2 t)+e^{-t} \cos (2 t) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

we get the final solution:

$$x(t)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{-t} \left(x_{10} (\cos (2 t)-2 \sin (2 t))+5 \left(x_{20} \sin (2 t)+2 e^t-4 \sin (2 t)-2 \cos (2 t)\right)\right) \\
 e^{-t} \left(-x_{10} \sin (2 t)+x_{20} (2 \sin (2 t)+\cos (2 t))+8 e^t-6 \sin (2 t)-8 \cos (2 t)\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$